# Add custom js to magento 2 after jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

I try to add a custom js to magento 2 head, but after the jquery.js.
Or is there a way to add the custom js file to the footer?

I have tried in the default.xml but it's over the jquery.js

This is my code in default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <script src="js/myjsfile.js"/>
  </body></page>
```

Comment: please show your actual code, which you have tried.

Comment: I have added the code to my question.

Comment: you can do it using requirejs-config.js file to call after jquery.

Comment: ok, and without requirejs-config.js? Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Require JS to add the JS, loading it via the XML is not best practice. This is because Require JS can track dependencies and only load scripts when required, instead of unnecessarily loading scripts and creating a maze of confusing dependencies.

To load JS via Require JS follow these steps:

#### Template:

In your template add:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized on the element defined by selector
    "<element_selector>": {
        "<js_component1>": ...,
        "<js_component2>": ...
    },
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "<js_component3>": ...
    }
}
</script>
```

Where `<js_component#>`is the path to your JS, or alternatively the name of the module if you've mapped it with Require JS.

#### Script

Then write your JS inside Require like so:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'anotherDependency'
    ], function ($) {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Map** In `requirejs-config.js` of your module:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'module-name': 'path/to/script'
        }
    }
};
```

Don't use .js at the end of the script

**2.Html.**

```
<div data-mage-init='{"module-name":{}}'>
   <!-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

**3.Your Script**

```
//path/to/script.js

define(["jquery"], function($){
    //Your stuffs
});
```

If you put "jquery" as a dependency in your definition function your script will be loaded before jquery

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to add the custom js file to the footer.

By adding the js file into the `requirejs-config.js` and also in the `default.xml`.

Comment: You have no need to include your script in layout file if you use require.